# session variables not working across different pages

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Once i logged in i set a session variable inside body element(inside login.php) as below:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['Username'] = $_POST["Username"];

if(isset($_SESSION['Username']))
    $loginTrue = 1;
else
    $loginTrue = 0;
```

and on top every page i have added this

```
<?php 
session_start();          //this was added after seeing many suggestions in stack overflow that session_start() has to be called at the top on each page. Though i tot calling once was sufficient.
if(isset($_SESSION['Username']))
    $loginTrue = 1;
else
    $loginTrue = 0;
?>
```

Now whenever i redirect my page after login from login.php $_SESSION['Username'] gets unset, i dont know how. I redirect using a button click as in
onclick execute window.location = home.php

Comment: could it be because $_POST["Username"] is empty ? try using $_POST['Username'] and see if that works.

Comment: in the page where you are receiving the POST do a `print_r($_POST)` to check if it isn't empty

Comment: no they are all perfectly fine because when i print $_SESSION['Username'] it prints perfectly fine in the logged in page

$loginTrue is 1 when i log in then whenever i redirect it becomes 0 as in it resets. Is there anyting like the redirect link i.e window.location = "http://localhost:8080/home.php"??? should i compulsorily  use http??? btw even this didn work. i just wanted to know!!!

Comment: alright guys i solved it somehow. I dont know how i did but i did.
Firstly i created 4 webpages, a small one just to check the if session variables are supported. Once i confirmed this then i did the below and my original webpage started working

session start is very important at top of all pages. Also try session activity in different browsers. Also check by closing dreamweaver. Also make sure <!DOCTYPE html> is used instead of transitional and stuff and also that session start comes before doctype html declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright guys i solved it somehow. I dont know how i did but i did. Firstly i created 4 webpages, a small one just to check the if session variables are supported. Once i confirmed this then i did the below and my original webpage started working session start is very important at top of all pages. Also try session activity in different browsers. Also check by closing dreamweaver. Also make sure  is used instead of transitional and stuff and also that session start comes before doctype html declaration

Answer (score 1):

This is not comman 
check your code with this code may be some error is on the page

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
?>
```

And check your php.ini setting for this.

And check your code with different browser.

And any blank output should be on your page before session start.